# How much heat will a Vermont Bun Baker wood stove put off?

Tags: woodstove

My home is 750 Square Feet and also has radiant heating. I'm considering replacing my large, inefficient Garrison wood stove with the Bun Baker, and curious about the potential of using it as an equivalent replacement. I'm concerned how much heat it will actually put off and I do not intend to use the soapstone veneer.

Answer (score 5):

A place to start would be the heat output rating. The Vermont Bun Baker is rated at 30,000 Btu/hr. The Garrison wood stove (1976 model 2) is rated at 37,000 Btu/hr. But these are hard to compare since the newer oven is likely the EPA rating and the older one is likely a maximum output rating.

Then you need to consider how fast your home loses heat, outside temperatures, etc. The manufacturer claims the Bun Baker will heat 700-900 sq. ft. The comments from owners seem to agree.

- [Vermont Bun Baker Wood Cook Stove](http://woodstoves.net/cookstoves/vermontbunbaker.htm)
- [Garrison Wood Stove Baffle warping Problem](http://www.hearth.com/talk/threads/garrison-wood-stove-baffle-warping-problem.104162/)
- [EPA efficiency & heat output ratings:
  Why do they differ from what I see on manufacturers' brochures?](http://chimneysweeponline.com/hobtucmp.htm)

Comment: That's great advice. The house is newer construction and 6" framing with good insulation. most windows are pretty good. I should have also added one more piece to the puzzle: the house has a radiant slab from an on-demand propane water heater. The floor is a pretty good heat sink.